# What determines the title given to players at the end of a battle in Crash Team Racing?

Tags: crash-team-racing

I'm playing the original CTR and I'm wondering what triggers the messages displayed for each player at the end of Battle \ VS modes, i.e. "dominator", "speed demon", etc.

I couldn't find it on Google or any cheat code pages. Is there any official or unofficial site ever covered this?

Comment: It looks like that the Prima strategy guide doesn't contain the terms you mentioned.